# SQL splitting variable strings with a GUID?

Tags: sql, string, sql-server-2008-r2, split, guid

I ran into another infamous SQL server string splitting challenge.

Here's what the data (ActiveDirectory groups) looks like that I have available:

```
Domain1\EDE_C_SD_C292F61A-4432-4D4B-84B4-7D8250B551C8_DENY
Domain2\TIP_C_C59123C9-8F06-4C8C-BCAC-B15FAE8D41F1_DENY
Domain1\MAL_G_C_GLOBAL-UPDATE_690B3861-CC86-4995-B8E3-921B8793D1DA_DENY
Domain1\APPEDK_C_SD_SOMETEXT_690B3861-CC86-4995-B8E3-921B8793D1DA_DENY
Domain1\APPEDK_C_SD_C59123C9-8F06-4C8C-BCAC-B15FAE8D41F1_DENY
Domain1\MAL_G_C_GLOBAL-UPDATE_BCA567DA-B1D7-4E9B-B181-DDDC007D65E0_DENY
Domain1\WOL_C_SD_690B3861-CC86-4995-B8E3-921B8793D1DA_DENY
Domain2\GAL_C_C59123C9-8F06-4C8C-BCAC-B15FAE8D41F1_DENY
Domain1\ESS_C_SD_690B3861-CC86-4995-B8E3-921B8793D1DA_DENY
```

There is one underlying syntax rule: all strings end with [GUID]_DENY whereas the group prefix can be anything

I need to split the string so that the result looks like this:

```
Domain  | Prefix    | GUID
Domain1 | EDE_C_SD_ | C292F61A-4432-4D4B-84B4-7D8250B551C8
Domain2 | TIP_C_    | C59123C9-8F06-4C8C-BCAC-B15FAE8D41F1
```

etc.

Running on SQL Server 2008 R2 I'm a bit stuck :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combine charindex and substring

```
select 
  SUBSTRING ( a , 0, charindex('\\', a )) as Domain,
  SUBSTRING ( a , charindex('\\', a ) + 2, len(a) - 36 - 5 - charindex('\\', a )) as Prefix,
  SUBSTRING ( a , len(a) - 36 - 5 + 1 , 36 ) as GUID from ad
```

where `ad` is your table and `a` is the column with the ad data.

Full [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ba36c/9/0).

Comment: this works just fine, even though I was somehow hoping for a proper GUID detection, but I can put that in my WHERE clause :) thanks!